# Find/index pair of characters as well (digraphs, trigraphs) in strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

Working with two *JavaScript* *Object*:

1. a dynamic *String* like `"SZERETET"`
2. and a constant *Array*: `[["A", "a"], ["Á", "á"], ["B", "eb"], ["C", "ec"], ["Cs", "ecs"], ["D", "ed"], ["Dz", "dzé"], ["Dzs", "dzsé"], ["E", "e"], ["É", "é"], ["F", "ef"], ["G", "eg"], ["Gy", "egy"], ["H", "eh"], ["I", "i"], ["Í", "í"], ["J", "ej"], ["K", "ek"], ["K", "ak"], ["L", "el"], ["Ly", "elly, el-ipszilon"], ["M", "em"], ["N", "en"], ["Ny", "eny"], ["O", "o"], ["Ó", "ó"], ["Ö", "ö"], ["Ő", "ő"], ["P", "ep"], ["Q", "eq"], ["R", "er"], ["S", "es"], ["Sz", "esz"], ["T", "et"], ["Ty", "ety"], ["U", "u"], ["Ú", "ú"], ["Ü", "ü"], ["Ű", "ű"], ["V", "ev"], ["W", "dupla vé"], ["X", "iksz"], ["Y", "ipszilon"], ["Z", "ez"], ["Zs", "ezs"]]`

I am searching for the solution to create another *Array* based on the *String* and the elements of the existing Array as follows:

```
["Sz","E","R","E","T","E","T"]
```

I wasn't able to reach further than this. Please help me out.

```js
    const szoStr = "SzerEtet";
    const abcArr = [["A", "a"], ["Á", "á"], ["B", "eb"], ["C", "ec"], ["Cs", "ecs"], ["D", "ed"], ["Dz", "dzé"], ["Dzs", "dzsé"], ["E", "e"], ["É", "é"], ["F", "ef"], ["G", "eg"], ["Gy", "egy"], ["H", "eh"], ["I", "i"], ["Í", "í"], ["J", "ej"], ["K", "ek"], ["K", "ak"], ["L", "el"], ["Ly", "elly, el-ipszilon"], ["M", "em"], ["N", "en"], ["Ny", "eny"], ["O", "o"], ["Ó", "ó"], ["Ö", "ö"], ["Ő", "ő"], ["P", "ep"], ["Q", "eq"], ["R", "er"], ["S", "es"], ["Sz", "esz"], ["T", "et"], ["Ty", "ety"], ["U", "u"], ["Ú", "ú"], ["Ü", "ü"], ["Ű", "ű"], ["V", "ev"], ["W", "dupla vé"], ["X", "iksz"], ["Y", "ipszilon"], ["Z", "ez"], ["Zs", "ezs"]];

const lengths = {}; // length of Array elements
abcArr.forEach((item) => {
  lengths[item[0]] = item[0].length;
});
// console.log(lengths);

const lengthsSorted = Object.entries(lengths).sort(([_, b], [__, a]) => a - b); // sort Array elements by lengths descending
// console.log(lengthsSorted);

const results = []; // desired Array: ["Sz","E","R","E","T","E","T"]
/*
lengthsSorted.forEach((item) => {
  var needle = item[0];
  var regexp = new RegExp(needle,'ig');
  while (regexp.exec(szoStr)){
    results[item[0]] = regexp.lastIndex;
//    console.log(abcArr.findIndex((ind) => ind[0] === item[0]));
//    console.log(abcArr[abcArr.findIndex((ind) => ind[0] === item[0])][0]);
  }
});
*/
/*
lengthsSorted.forEach((item) => {
  var search = szoStr.toUpperCase().search(item[0].toUpperCase());
  if (search>=0)
    console.log(search+item[0]);
//    console.log(abcArr.findIndex((ind) => ind[0] === item[0]));
//    console.log(abcArr[abcArr.findIndex((ind) => ind[0] === item[0])][0]);
});
*/

function indxUC(item){
  return szoStr.toUpperCase().indexOf(item.toUpperCase());
}
let position = 0;
lengthsSorted.forEach((item) => {
  if (indxUC(item[0])>=0 && indxUC(item[0]) >= position) { // Prevent including digraph's characters to be included   
//    console.log([indxUC(item[0]),item[0].length,position]);
//    console.log(abcArr.findIndex((ind) => ind[0] === item[0]));
    results.push(abcArr[abcArr.findIndex((ind) => ind[0] === item[0])][0]); // ["Sz","E","R","T"]
    position++;
  }
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Is ["S","Z","E","R","E","T","E","T"] also a solution?

Comment: Yes @ReallyMadeMeThink `["S","Z","E","R","E","T","E","T"]` needs to be the solution but wasn't able to reach that point

Comment: So is ["Sz","E","R","E","T","E","T"] not the intended result? Or are both acceptable solutions?

Comment: Case-insensitive is the best, but the digraphs are in the database like this: "Sz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex `| - OR`

**Note:** Here I changed the order of `"S", "Sz"` to `"Sz", "S"` in the constant array. You have to change other orders also for better results

```js
const szoStr = "SzerEtet"

const abcArr = [["A", "a"], ["Á", "á"], ["B", "eb"], ["C", "ec"], ["Cs", "ecs"], ["D", "ed"], ["Dz", "dzé"], ["Dzs", "dzsé"], ["E", "e"], ["É", "é"], ["F", "ef"], ["G", "eg"], ["Gy", "egy"], ["H", "eh"], ["I", "i"], ["Í", "í"], ["J", "ej"], ["K", "ek"], ["K", "ak"], ["L", "el"], ["Ly", "elly, el-ipszilon"], ["M", "em"], ["N", "en"], ["Ny", "eny"], ["O", "o"], ["Ó", "ó"], ["Ö", "ö"], ["Ő", "ő"], ["P", "ep"], ["Q", "eq"], ["R", "er"], ["S", "es"], ["Sz", "esz"], ["T", "et"], ["Ty", "ety"], ["U", "u"], ["Ú", "ú"], ["Ü", "ü"], ["Ű", "ű"], ["V", "ev"], ["W", "dupla vé"], ["X", "iksz"], ["Y", "ipszilon"], ["Z", "ez"], ["Zs", "ezs"]]

const abcArrKeys = abcArr.map(i => i[0]).sort().reverse() // sort().reverse() not needed if you manually ordered as ["Sz"], ["S"] and ["Gy"], ["G"] 

const abcReg = new RegExp(abcArrKeys.join('|'), 'gi')

const result = szoStr.match(abcReg)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, forget to add the *multi-dimensional Array structure* to the question, as it is in the *snippet*. Editing now. Your answer is great, how can be compatible with the *multi-dimensional Array*?

Comment: I hope the next question should be the output text case. That doesn't require much effort, So I suggest you try it on your own.

Comment: A simple and elegant solution using [JavaScript Array join() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) and [JavaScript String match() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is not case sensitive. If you need it, I don't know how it can be done.

```js
//based on abcArr maximum length of the items can be 3 like "Dzs".
const maxL = 3;
let result = [];

function checkForMatch(i) {
    let start = szoStr[i];
    if (!start) {
        return;
    }

    let p, j;
    
    // This loop check "S", "Sz", "Sze" when first call.
    // When it find a match it makes result[i] = match
    // Since [i] doesn't change while iteration, "Sz" overwrites "S"

    for (j = 1; j <= maxL; j++) {
        let check = szoStr.slice(i, i + j);
        if (check.length === j) {
            let match = abcArr.find(
                x =>
                    x[0].toUpperCase() === check.toUpperCase() ||
                    x[0].toLowerCase() === check.toLowerCase()
            );
            if (match) {
                result[i] = match[0];
                p = i + j;
                result = result.filter(x => x !== undefined);
            }
        }
    }
    checkForMatch(p);
}

checkForMatch(0);

console.log("result :>> ", result);
result :>>  (7) ["Sz", "E", "R", "E", "T", "E", "T"]
```

Comment: Great code, thank you. Why do you use `if (check.length === j) {`…?

Comment: let check = szoStr.slice(i, i + j); this return the last letter 3 times, and if the statement limit it by 1. If you remove that, you can see extra "T" at the end of array.